# Can't enable Rhythmbox's Google Music Plugin

Tags: rhythmbox, music, plugins, google

I tried to install [Google Play Music Plugin](https://github.com/nvbn/rhythmbox-gmusic/) for Rhythmbox.

I ended up by getting the plugin installed but I can't enable it. :c

[image: pic]

**I have:**

Ubuntu 13.04 x32

Gnome 3.8

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I installed using PPA, but it didn't work. However, installing using PIP worked just fine:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip git-core
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/nvbn/rhythmbox-gmusic.git#egg=rhythmbox-gmusic
```

I also installed python-dateutil, python-requests and python-validictory.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this solved it under Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install gmusicapi --upgrade
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue as well. After some research I found this [http://github.com/nvbn/rhythmbox-gmusic/issues/24](https://github.com/nvbn/rhythmbox-gmusic/issues/24).

Try installing

- python-dateutil
- python-requests
- python-validictory

After installing these dependencies I had no issues.

Hope this helps.  Take care.

Comment: Unfortunately installing python dependencies you have suggested doesn't help me at all. Do you have any other suggestions? I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.