# Install Google Play Music Plugin for Rythmbox on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, music, plugins, google

I've tried to install [Google Play Music Plugin](https://github.com/nvbn/rhythmbox-gmusic/) for Rythmbox.
I've first tried to install it via PPA as described [here](https://github.com/nvbn/rhythmbox-gmusic/).

After executing

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-gmusic
```

I get an error message wich says (might not be the correct output in english since I hadd to translate it from german, but I think everyone knows whats happening)

```
packagelists are read... done
dependencytree gets build
statusinformation are read... done
some packages could not be installed[...]
the following information might help you, to solve your problem:

the following packages have unmet dependencies
 rhythmbox-gmusic : depends on: python-validictory but is not installable
E: problems can not be corrected, you have hold back damaged packages
```

So after this I've tried installing the plugin via via PIP as described [here](https://github.com/nvbn/rhythmbox-gmusic/)

This succeeded but I've try to enable the plugin I get a warning sign (red sign with wide horizontal line) like described in [this Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290516/cant-enable-rhythmboxs-google-music-plugin)

*Note: I've tried all 3 solutions given in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290516/cant-enable-rhythmboxs-google-music-plugin)*

But if I try installing python-validictory with

```
sudo apt-get install python-validictory
```

I get following output (again translated from german)

```
packagelists are read... done
dependencytree gets build
statusinformation are read... done
package python-validictory is not available, but is referenced in another package.
This can mean that the package is missing, that it got redeemed or is only available from another source.

E: package »python-validictory« has no installation candidate
```

Can someone please tell me how I can get python-validictory or how I get this plugin to work. Thank you in advance.

[Update]
I forgot to mention that I also looked at [this site](https://github.com/nvbn/rhythmbox-gmusic/issues/24) but don't know what

> These packages can all be installed fron universe/main.

means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These packages can all be installed from universe.

You have to enable universe repository.So that the `python-validictory` package would be installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"        # command to enable Universe repository

sudo apt-get update                                                                               # Command to update all repositories
sudo apt-get install python-validictory                                                           # Command to install python-validictory package
```

**Edit**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dput-ng-maint/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-validictory
```

**Edit**

After those commands run

```
sudo -i
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
exit
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install gmusicapi --upgrade
```

Now open your Rythmbox and enable the Google Play Music plugin.

Comment: I've tried your solution it seems that this repository was already enabled and it still couldn't install python-validictory. I still get the same error message

Comment: Now try my edit.

Comment: after I tried your edit, I was able to install python-validictory. But still couldn't enable the Google Play Music plugin. So I tried any solution from the above mentioned [Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/290516/cant-enable-rhythmboxs-google-music-plugin) and for some reason when I executed 
`sudo pip install gmusicapi --upgrade` 
I got an error message telling me
`ImportError: no module named pkg_resources`
But could solve this problem by using this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10538412/3375034)
_Note: I had to execute the command in this answer with sudo -i to make it work_

Comment: so after those steps I executed `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and `sudo pip install gmusicapi --upgrade` which finally did the trick